# create a try and catch inside loop

Tags: sql

I want to loop though the  "RPT_ID = 245 "  from 1 to 245 and inside the try and catch the invalid query statements so that the invalid queries will be caught.

The query column is a dynamic sql statement created for reports.

```
alter PROCEDURE usp_ExampleProc

AS
       declare 
    @vsql2        as nvarchar(max)
    ,@vquery2    as nvarchar(max)
    ,@value      as nvarchar(max)
    ,@value2     as nvarchar(max)
    ,@Q1     as nvarchar(max)
    ,@RP_NUM     as nvarchar(max)
    ,@count      as int

    select @count = count(*) from saved_reports

 while   @count > 0

     begin
       select  @q1 =  query,@RP_NUM =RPT_ID from SAVED_REPORTS WHERE RPT_ID = @count
       exec sys.sp_executesql @q1



BEGIN TRY
    EXECUTE usp_ExampleProc;
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
         ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
      set @count = @count - 1

     end
```

Comment: I don't see a loop or a question.

Comment: I see a loop... `while count > 0`... but I dont see a question :)

Answer (score 1):

use

EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo;

in your catch statement.

see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx